# Why am I getting the error datetime2 clashing with int?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a sp that inserts data from one table to another; when I run this, I get an operand type clash for line 7 (insert tab1); I am a bit confused as I can't clearly understand why there is a clash; to give you some context, tab1.date is datetime2. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong please?

```
declare @report_start date = NULL  

SET @report_start = ISNULL(@report_start , DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)); --If the date it's null, sets it as the first day of the year

Truncate table tab1;

insert tab1
SELECT
    tab2.Date as Date,
    DATENAME(dw,tab2.Date) as [Day of the Week],
    '00' +RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,CAST(REPLACE([Spot Length],' secs','') AS INT),0),108),5) AS [Length of the Spot (Source)] ,
    CASE 
        WHEN '00' +RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,CAST(REPLACE([Spot Length],' secs','') AS INT),0),108),5) in ('0000:01 ','0000:02 ','0000:03 ','0000:04 ','0000:05 ','0000:06 ') THEN '0000:05'
        ELSE '0001:03'
    END as [Updated Length],
    CASE
        WHEN tab2.[Date]='2018-01-01' THEN '2018/1'
        ELSE CAST(YEAR(tab2.[Date]-1) AS VARCHAR(4))+'/'+ cast( DATEPART( wk, tab2.[Date]-1) AS VARCHAR(2))
    END AS [Number of the Week],
    left(datename(month,tab2.[Date]),3)+'-'+ RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(tab2.[Date])),2) AS [month]
from tab2
left join category on tab2.Brand = category.Campaign
where tab2.Date>=@report_start
and tab2.Date <> (select max(date) from tab2)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Looks like SQL Server code?)

Comment: @jarlh apologies for not specifying; yes it is SSMS

Comment: No problem. With the <sql server> tag, your question will get the best attention!

Comment: Almost certainly caused by *not specifying your columns* for the `INSERT`. Can't tell for sure since we don't have the table definition, but it's a nasty habit anyway. Always *name* your columns and make sure the `insert` and `select`/`values` seem to broadly be in agreement.

Comment: @Jurij the error is clear - somewhere in all this there's an attempt to mix int and datetime2. Maybe there's an attempt to add an int and datetime2? Different column orders in INSERT and SELECT? An inappropriate cast? It's hard to say since you havent' provided the table creation schema so people can't test your query. Start commenting out sections until you find what's actually going on.

Comment: OT: though looking at this, it's clear that some syntax that allowed you to effectively say "take column names from the select query" could be quite appealing, in that it would eliminate the "match-by-position" nature of existing `INSERT` forms that I've never been a fan of.

Comment: Try just the "SELECT" part of that "insert tab1 SELECT ..." query. Are the column values/types (and order) those that are expected in that tab1 table?

Comment: thank you everyone for your comments; apologies for not having included the table creation schema, that was fairly crucial! all solved btw

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the first column of `tab1` is of type `INT`, possibly the Primary Key. You didn't tell the INSERT what columns to insert, so the INSERT is expecting to be fed all of `tab1`s columns in the order that they have been defined. The result is that it tries to put the value of `SELECT ... as [DATE]` into the INT column.

To overcome this, specify the columns in the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT tab1 ([Date], [Day of the Week], ...)
SELECT
    tab2.Date as Date,
    DATENAME(dw,tab2.Date) as [Day of the Week],
    ...
```

If the `INT` that we are now skipping is indeed the Primary Key of `tab1` then this will work if it is using `IDENTITY()`. If not, then you'll have to find a way to generate suitable PK values in the `SELECT`.